# how to find the distance of the root from the origin?

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, autoregressive-model

Good Day, I have 9 polynomial roots. i have plotted the roots. my problems are:

1)how to find the distance of the roots from origin? I want to find the distance of all the roots from the origin.

2) I have 3 models and I want to differentiate between them using the polynomial roots. I want to observes how the roots are moving from each models. Is it possible for me to arrange the roots in ascending order? the one that is closer to the origin and farther from the origin.

Any idea? Looking for your reply. Thanks!

Comment: The roots are generally complex numbers, so their distance from the origin is simply the magnitude of that complex number. The same is of course true for the special case that the root is real-valued.

Comment: @Matt L. thanks for the reply. how about my second problem sir?